# Macbook Pro M1 momentarily goes black on an external display

Tags: display, thunderbolt, apple-silicon

I have a Samsung M7 screen connected to my Macbook Pro M1 via a thunderbolt 3 cable. Occasionally, e.g., once daily, the screen momentarily goes black for a second. I did not have the same problem when it was connected with an HDMI cable. Is it a cable problem?

EDIT: It seems that the issue is related to that [particular monitor](https://www.reddit.com/r/macsetups/comments/ohfl62/samsung_monitor_m7_macbook_pro_m1_display_going/)

Comment: There's not much to work with here. What brand of Tbolt cable? Can you test with another Tbolt 3 cable? What's the external screen res? Are you using a specific app when this happens or are you switching between apps when it happens? Does it happen at approximately the same time every day? Does it happen reliably after x numbers of hours being connected? Do you close the MBP lid and use just the external screen? If you do close the lid, does the screen go black at some point after you open the lid? What version of macOS is running on your MBP? If you jiggle the cable, does it occur?

Comment: @IconDaemon Cable is UGreen, Screen is UHD, not related to switching between apps, Laptop lid always closed, not sure about the timing, macos 11.6.5, jiggling the cable does not produce the problem, cannot test with another cable, don't think it happens with a specific app, but maybe related to the move movement of the mouse.

Comment: THB/ some 3rd party accessories (dongles, cables, etc) just aren't up to spec sometimes. After much experimentation with numerous dongles over the years, the Belkin and increasingly, the Anker brand of accessories have proved their mettle. I can't prove that your UGreen cable is at fault, but a colleague testing a UGreen product a few years ago (can't remember which) put it on the no-purchase list. Note: I have received no financial or other compensation from Belkin nor Anker.